# SMS url without a number specified ( share button ) on android 9

Tags: android, url, sms, share

My landing page implementation ( html & javascript) of share via sms button ( sms link without any number, for example sms:///?body=test ) is no longer working with android 9  -- i'm getting illegal contact\destination message when clicked

Any ideas how to overcome this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried removing the /// from your link?

It doesn't seem to be a part of the [SMS URI scheme](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5724#section-2.5)

Instead try

```
<a href="sms:?body=Hello">
```

Comment: @NitzanDavari this does not seem to be working on my Pixel 2.  What device are you using?

Comment: This fix worked for me on a Samsung Galaxy S7, Android 7.0.

Comment: worked for me with Samsung Galaxy S8 & Note 8 both with android 9